# Is there a MS Graph API for Microsoft Stream?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, video-streaming, microsoft365

I'd like to present a video on my website, which is hosted on OneDrive for Bussiness / Sharepoint. The new Microsoft Stream for Sharepoint allows users to stream the video with a variety of resolution through CDN at portal.
How could I provide same features (different resolution and CDN) on my website (not Sharepoint, not intranet) just as the portal? Does MS Graph provides the very API?

Answer (score 0):

Video for Microsoft Stream for SharePoint is just the normal Graph API file represented by `driveItem` resource.

Through Graph API you can upload/download/delete/modify a video file.

For example, here are some kinds of things you can do with video file in Graph API:

- Upload: [driveItem: createUploadSession - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0)
- Delete: [Delete a file or folder - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- Get view analytics: [Get itemAnalytics - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/itemanalytics-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
- Get embed code: [driveItem: preview - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-1.0)
- Move: [Move a file or folder - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

For the [preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-1.0) I don't see any option to specify resolution or CDN.

Some newer API features for videos (transcripts, thumbnails, chapters, etc.) are not public and documented

You can suggest a new idea for API to set a resolution and CDN on [feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/search/776075da-1b1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472?q=api)